# Animating a CSS linear-gradient's change in percentage values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, linear-gradients

I am making a game where the score is tracked in a progress bar as a percentage of the total possible points.

Right now, I have a javascript method that updates the background's linear-gradient percentage, which results in the bar updating instantaneously to its new position based on the value of the percentage variable:

```
document.getElementById("pointThreshold").style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 230, 0) ' + percentage + '%, #1b1f20 0%)';
```

This code works and the progress bar updates properly, but I would like to be able to animate the change in that percentage. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Is this an easy thing to do?

I've managed to get the progress bar to update instantly, but not in an animated format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an "easy thing to do", no. CSS can do animation for almost everything except linear gradients. You just picked the worst possible way to draw a progress bar.

One thing you could do is a bit complicated if you absolutely must use a gradient:

- Scale the gradient background up to twice the size of the container using `background-size`.
- Control the gradient's position using `background-position`
- Animate `background-position` using `transition`

Run this code snippet and click on the yellow rectangle to watch the animated change. The JavaScript sets `.style.backgroundPosition = "50%";` to trigger that change, and CSS handles animating it smoothly.

```js
document.querySelector( "div" ).onclick = function() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "50%";
}
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 230, 0) 50%, #1b1f20 50.1% );
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: 0%;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Finally, unless you are required to use gradients, I wouldn't. All these things are much easier to work with than gradients: borders, box-shadows, images, and absolute-positioned child elements. CSS can animate all of those very easily with a single line.

Here's the same effect, achieved using a yellow border on the left of the box, instead of a linear gradient. Click the black rectangle to see the yellow border animate smoothly to a larger size.

```js
document.querySelector( "div" ).onclick = function() {
    this.style.borderWidth = "0 0 0 " + 100 + "px";
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    border:0px solid yellow;
    transition: border-width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of a proper way to do this. I'll use that for next time. Interestingly enough I was able to get it to work using your first example by subtracting the percentage from 100; using the actual percentage was pushing the bar in the wrong direction.